# Batch command to make network location private?

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file, location, private

I am having quite a lot of difficulty running 2 simultaneous connections on 1 pc. I disable and enable often (long story) and this changes my network location.

I am using Windows 8. I would like to know the code for a batch file that will change my network location to private. I know there are other ways to do it, but those are too long. i.e. running through the homegroup troubleshooter which eventually gives me the option to change my network location to private.

Please, I want the BATCH file code. Thanks soo much for the help! I really have been struggling on this for a very long time! Thank you!

Comment: FYI - This question seems more appropriate for the SuperUsers group.  You may get a better response if you post your question there (http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used `netsh` to manage lots of the configuration settings of a NIC (interface card).  However, I don't see anything to manage the network location.

A quick Google search turned up the following link that shows how to manage the network location from PowerShell, with an additional .dll from Microsoft:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/10/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-manage-windows-network-locations.aspx

It's quite lengthy, so pasting the relevant portions here really isn't practical.

Alternatively, you could try using the CMD prompt to enable/disable the NICs (if you are using the Windows GUI).  I found the CMD route to be less problematic than the Windows GUI.  To use the CMD prompt, you need to obtain `devcon.exe`.  I found it in a Microsoft SDK.  Once you have it, you can type the following from the CMD prompt:

```
devcon listclass net
```

This will show your NICs.  Then type:

```
devcon hwids __________
```

Fill in the blank with the first part of the NIC id (e.g., `PCI\VEN_14E4`).  This will give you the hardware IDs for the NIC.  I use the following to enable/disable my Ethernet and WiFi NICs.

```
devcon enable PCI\CC_020000
devcon disable PCI\CC_020000
devcon enable PCI\CC_028000
devcon disable PCI\CC_028000
```